# How can I replace the value of a field(s) based on another field(s) in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I need to replace some values that I get from a database with the values of another field (same database), providing the other field is populated.

In my database I have the following fields (amongst others): RMM, RMY, IRM, IRY

If IRM is populated I need to replace the value in RMM.

If IRY is populated I need to replace the value in RMY.

If IRM / IRY are not populated, then RMM / RMY remain as they are.

I’ve created a filter which checks if IRM or IRY are null, if they aren’t, I have a **set field value** step where I set the respective values.
I then use the **append streams** step to merge the path where the filter fails.

However, the problem with my current solution is that the **or** condition in my filter is causing some of the values to be replaced by nulls - since the condition in the filter only needs one side to be true.

Here is my current solution:

[transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StuKx.png)

[filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP9M6.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do away with the Filter and the step and use a simple Formula step that , one for each column, that updates the value of RMM and RMY based on the value of IRM and IRY:

[image]

This way you are working on both columns separetely, testing nulls and replacing when needed.